Does this tree-navigation-like problem has a name? (Minimal inputs s.t. a problem is unsolvable)
I have a problem $P$ on a graph such that some nodes have input ${0, 1}$ on some nodes $S_{init}$. From now on I will use "input on $S$" to mean the output on nodes on $S$ must match the input. The problem is not very relevant - a version of a coloring.
I know that for some inputs $P$ is not solvable and I'm looking for the "minimal reason" such that $P$ is not solvable - aka inputs on $S \subset S_{init}$ such that $P$ is still not solvable but for all $S'\subsetneq S$, $P$ is solvable.
This is how I figured how to find all such sets. In a tree, a node is represented by an assignment of vertices by ${1, 0}$ or $X$, $X$ meaning no input and the others beeing pretty self explanatory. Then I process the tree in the following way:

we traverse the tree in a BFS way.

when we visit a node, for each part of the assignment that is not $X$ yet, I look if $P$ would be solvable if the corresponding node had no assignment. If yes, we forget about it, If no, we create the corresponding child.

If after processing, a node still has no child, then it correspond to an input I want to look at.


So I think in principle it should work. When I got into the coding myself I realized I don't even need a tree structure. Indeed we never care when a node has children, so we might as well forget them, so I'll go for an even simpler structure.
However this problem seems like a pretty basic one.  so I was wondering if it is a known thing and what are the best algorithms for it.

You probably need to give more information about $P$. What does it mean for it to be solvable?

@MathieuRundström it is some variation of a coloring problem. Something that maybe is not clear is that the input on $S$ = fixing the solution on the nodes in $S$, and solving $P$ is assigning 0 or 1 to nodes. Hence the less "input" you have the the easier it is to solve $P$.

I don't quite follow the details, but it reminds me of when I wrote a Sudoku puzzle generator, where you want to select which cells to use as clues, and generally you want as few clues as possible. I tried two methods. First, start with an empty grid and add valid clues at random until the rest of the sudoku grid had a unique solution. This was too slow. Second, start with a full grid and remove clues as long as the solution remains unique, until all remaining clues have been tested and shown to be necessary. This was a lot faster despite having more iterations. Anyway, just some thoughts.

By "solvable", I guess you mean either that that the partial assignment is consistent with your constraint and the level of consistency you are maintaining, or that your partial assignment can always can always be extended to a solution (In this case, we sometimes say that the partial assignment is globally consistent) and by "non solvable", that you identified a conflict (a set of assignments that cannot be extended to a solution).
You are trying to find smaller (ideally minimal) conflicts, that we call "nogood", or also "lazy clause" in SAT solving.

In constraint programming, the detection of conflicts is generally used to reduce the size of the search. Basically, if we encounter a conflict in the search tree, we identify a small conflict, and add a constraint that explicitly forbid this conflict. We talk of "nogood learning" or "clause learning". There are other ways to reduce the size of conflicts that may be more effective than finding the smallest one. In the CDCL algorithm, the nogood is determined by finding a cut in the implication graph.
A lighter approach is to detect the first decision in the search tree that leads to the conflict, and to "backjump" to this decision.

Here, you seem just interested to reduce the size of the conflict to give a "minimal explanation" of why a particular problem $P$ is not feasible. This is a big topic of constraint programming, known as "explainable constraint solving". In the easiest understanding of "explaining", this boils down to finding a minimal set of constraints that is conflicting (Minimal Unsatisfiable Set - MUS). Here, you just give a subset $S$ of the initial partial assignment. In terms of constraint programming explanation, your explanation is the full set of constraints of $P$, and the constraints that fix the variables of $S$.
I don't know very much about this line of research, but there are a lot of clever optimizations that can be made.
I don't know if you already do this optimization, but if you remove constraint $A$, then $B$, and $B$ then $A$, the subtrees will be identical and should only be explored once.
A very powerful tool is the use of rotation theory: When an assoc is found (a constraint that can't be removed while keeping the problem unsatisfiable), we can find other such assocs by performing rotations, all those new assocs will no longer need to be tested for deletion, which can save a lot of satisfiability tests (see http://www.a4cp.org/cp2012/slides/modelrotate.pdf, https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-33558-7_49)

I'm not sure I completely understood your first sentence - basically the partial assignment is consistent with the problem; but problems arise on other nodes. For instance, 2-coloring a path of length 4, but the leaves have the same color.

@Qise I think I understand better what you are trying to achieve, I added more informations

Thanks for the details. As for your remark of A then B and B then A, I noticed it already; I managed it by removing nodes always in increasing order of their IDs
